# How to automatically start a GitHub Codespace with some Python packages?

Tags: python, github, github-codespaces

I started using Codespaces for small modifications in my open-source Python repositories. Most of them require only 2 core dependencies, `pre-commit` and `nox`. Is it possible to save a codespace configuration where these 2 libraries are automatically installed every time I create a new codespace?

Even better if this configuration can be scoped for each repository for small adjustments.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/setting-up-your-python-project-for-codespaces#step-3-modify-your-devcontainerjson-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the build of a custom codespace you need to configure the devcontainer. Create a `.devcontainer` directory at the root of your repository. in this folder create a `.devcontainer.json` file. Here is the minimal container I use to build an environment with Python tools:

```json
//.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
  "name": "Python 3",
  // use the latest python image
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python",
  // install libs after the creation of the environement 
  // by using a simple bash command
  "postCreateCommand": "python -m pip install nox pre-commit && pre-commit install"
}
```

GitHub Codespaces cannot handle multiple-line post create commands, thus the use of `&&`. As suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3527), you can also use a `.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh`:

```bash
#.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh
pip install nox pre-commit &&
pre-commit install
```

```json
//.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
  "name": "Python 3",
  // use the latest python image
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python",
  // install libs after the creation of the environement 
  // by using a simple bash command
  "postCreateCommand": "./.devcontainer/postCreateCommand.sh"
}
```

Instead of using the classic `pip install xxx` you can also search if the libraries you need to include exist in the image features by using the codespace VS Code extension as suggested [in GitHub's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/introduction-to-dev-containers). The previous JSON file would become:

```json
//.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/nox:2": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/pre-commit:2": {}
    },
    "postCreateCommand": "pre-commit install"
}
```